# FTP: After mget *text*, the server responds with a ? then says BYE, even with -i

Tags: ftp

I can't figure out why the ftp site isn't getting 2 files, both of which match the wildcard MGET command.  It almost appears there is a interactive prompt issue, (and yes, I've searched S.O. for other threads, which is why I'm now using the -i switch), but somehow when I do it manually - the EXACT SAME COMMAND, I can see that the server is prompting me.

When I use my batch file to automate it and refer to a command file, it acts offended that I can't interact with it, and it does not download the file.  A screenshot of how it looks when I use the batch file is attached.

Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: Try sending `PROMPT OFF` so it doesn't ask stupid questions.

Comment: Or maybe just `PROMPT` - I can't remember.

Comment: Oh - that did it.  Thanks!  Weird how FTP seems like such an non-exact science.  (I know that's not really true - just frustrating there are so many different flavors of server communication).  Anyway so when I did the mget, it got all csv files, for example it downloaded a file called "CheckoutReport_ID=4553_20140929-0000AM_20140930-0000AM.csv", even though this was my mget command: mget -i  *_20141004*

Have I forgotten something real basic about wildcards here, or can you tell what's going on?

Comment: Sorry, I have never even heard of `mget -i`.

Comment: EDIT, I guess the wildcard is a one-way deal.  Beginning or end of the file.  Fair enough I guess.  Thanks a bunch!